# Extract warehouse mappings as creation script

Tags: sql, oracle, string

Anyone know of a pure sql method for extracting mapping creation scripts from Oracle? the following SQL returns the right results:

```
SELECT text FROM dba_source WHERE NAME = 'MAPPING_NAME' AND TYPE = 'PACKAGE';
```

But in order to turn this into a single line, I've used a tip from http://dotnetsurfers.com/blog/2008/01/16/concatenating-rows-in-a-table-into-a-single-string-using-sql/ so now I have this:

```
SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(text, ' ') PackageScript FROM (
  SELECT text, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by line) rownumber, COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
  FROM (SELECT text, line FROM dba_source WHERE NAME = 'MAPPING_NAME' AND TYPE = 'PACKAGE' AND substr(text, 0,2) != '--' AND text IS NOT NULL)
) data
WHERE rownumber = cnt
START WITH rownumber = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rownumber = rownumber-1;
```

The problem is that oracle can't concatenate a string if the result is more than 4000 chars. It throws an error:

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

The following will pull out the ddl for an object.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('object_type_goes_here','object_name_goes_here','owner_goes_here') 
from dual
```